# multiline description for sublime text snippet

Tags: sublimetext, code-snippets, multiline

i want to display the description for a given sublime text snippet in multi line
i've created a simple alert() snippet 
but i want to display the description(in the description tag ) in multi line
for example 
 line 1
 line 2 
 line 3

here is the simple snippet :

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[   alert("${1:val}");${2:} ]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet
    -->
    <tabTrigger>Alt</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope>
    -->
    <description>simple javascript alert function</description>
    <description>second line </description>
</snippet>
```

Answer (score 2):

No that is not possible.

Only one `<description>` is recognized, the first one, any subsequent `<description>` entries are simply ignored.

Placing a carriage return inside the tag just results in it being replaced with a space.

```
e.g.
<description>This is a long description which has
been placed onto 2 lines.></description>

-> This is a long description which has been placed onto 2 lines.
```

Using `\n`, `\\n`, `\\\n` or `\\\\n` to insert a carriage return just results in the `\n` being treated literally.

```
e.g.
<description>This description has \n a newline entity.></description>

-> This description has \n a newline entity.
```

Both of these are also treated literally: `\r` (plus extra backslashes) and unicode `U+000D`.

Using either of these entities `&#13;` and `&#x0D;` results in the control character `CR` being printed but no actual new line. While these `&#10;`, `&#x0A;` are converted to spaces.

Using `CDATA` (character data which is not parsed by the XML parser) in the same way as `<content>` uses it, just results in the same as above. An actual newline in the file is converted to a space, and the various entities are either treated literally or converted to spaces.

```
<description><![CDATA[This is a long description,
which is split onto 2 lines.]]></description>

-> This is a long description, which is split onto 2 lines.
```

'sublime-snippet' files are simplified XML files. Possibly the XML string data type used is `xs:normalizedString` which will result in the XML parser automatically removing line feeds, carriage returns, and tab characters, but probably there is some code which strips all whitespace apart from spaces from the description string.

The Sublime Text snippet UI selector is probably designed in such a way to require a single line for snippet names and descriptions with no code written to handle a multiline description and I've never seen the overlay control displaying a multiline description whatever mode it's in (command palette, symbol, snippet, etc.).

Hope this helps.

Comment: so the only solution here is to create copies for the same snippet and  put the same snippet core in each file the only difference is the description tab  for example put < line1  of the description> in the first file and <line2 of the description > in the second line and so one ,but i think that this solution isn't smart enought

Comment: put line1 of the description in the first copy with the name copy1.sublime-snippet and the line2 of the description in the second copy with the name copy2.sublime-snippet and so one